# Installed GraphAware Framework under Ubuntu; not seeing any ga.* procedures in Neo4j browser

Tags: ubuntu, neo4j, graphaware

I am not seeing any procedures (ga.*) in results for "call dbms.procedures()"

My environment:
Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS,
Neo4j EE 3.0.7,
GraphAware plugins: graphaware-server-community-all-3.0.7.44.jar, graphaware-timetree-3.0.7.44.26.jar

I added com.graphaware.runtime.enabled=true to neo4j.conf

I restarted the neo4j server

neo4j.log reports "GraphAware started."

Any help you can give me would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Joel

Comment: Can you paste your neo4j.conf file contents for the timetree configuration

Comment: The neo4j.conf file is too long to post into a comment...the only lines that were added to the original are:dbms.connector.http.address=0.0.0.0:7474
dbms.connector.bolt.address=0.0.0.0:7687
com.graphaware.runtime.enabled=true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to have the Timetree module loaded, you will need to add those lines to the configuration :

```
#For the framework to work at all, you need this
dbms.unmanaged_extension_classes=com.graphaware.server=/graphaware

# Runtime must be enabled like this
com.graphaware.runtime.enabled=true

# A Runtime module that takes care of attaching the events like this (TT is the ID of the module)
com.graphaware.module.TT.1=com.graphaware.module.timetree.module.TimeTreeModuleBootstrapper
```

Moreover, there is the possibility to use automatic attachment of the event nodes to the timetree

https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-timetree#automatic-event-attachment

Comment: Yes, that worked, thank you.   Clearly, I overlooked something in an important readme somewhere.  Would you be kind enough to direct me to the online reference that I missed?  The automatic event attachment looks  great, will check it out

Comment: https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-timetree#automatic-event-attachment